# Indexes in SQLite and ordering of rows based on PK

Tags: android, database, sqlite, indexing

Does a PK in SQLite guarantee order of data?
AFAIK indexes implementation store data in-order of PK.
Does this apply for SQLite? Even for a composite PK?

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#orderby) says:

> If a SELECT statement that returns more than one row does not have an ORDER BY clause, the order in which the rows are returned is undefined.

The presence of a primary key or any other index does not change this; there is no guarantee that that index is actually used for the query.

If you want the output of a query to be sorted, you must use an ORDER BY. (If the ordering can be trivially implemented with the index, this will not be any less efficient that the same query without the ORDER BY clause.)

Comment: Now I am confused. They same something else here: https://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html (check Sorting By Rowid)

Comment: I assume Rowid is the auto-increment PK?

Comment: That page says exactly the same; "no sorting will be done" means that the DB will not do an explicit sorting step. Reading the data in the `rowid` order implies that the result already is correctly sorted.

Comment: Yes but this is because the insert order is maintained right?

Comment: If you're actually using autoincrementing IDs, insert order is the `rowid` order.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want know the underly implementation about indexes in SQLite and how does SQLite store data on the disk? Maybe help you at [File Format For SQLite Databases](http://www.sqlite.com/fileformat2.html) and [Here](https://github.com/PengJi/sqlite-doc) in chinese.